# How to retrieve a modelAttribute from HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, reflection, interceptor

I have a class that extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
public class AreaRiservataInterceptorAdapter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {        
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception 
    {}
}
```

I need it since I have to "edit" the object **Utente**, that you can see as parameter in this controller; with `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` I intercept the request before it is sent to this controller

```
    @Controller
    public class AreaRiservata{
    @RequestMapping("/prv/areaRiservataPost")
        public String areaRiservataPost(Model model, Utente utente){}   
   }
```

As I told before, I have to "edit" the object `Utente` inside the method `preHandle` of the class that extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.
I don't understand where I can retrieve the object `Utente`.
From the request? Form `Object handler`?

It's easy to do it in the method `postHandle`, since I can get it from the parameter `ModelAndView`, but I don't know how to do it inside `preHandle`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#preHandle` method would be called before argument `Utente` would be unmarshalled and passed to `#areaRiservataPost`.

> see spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java:919
>
> and org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod#getMethodArgumentValues

Therefore, you can't effect on object, which is not yet created. but, you can get data from request:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

unmarshal and then put the object `Utente` into `request` which would be then retrieved and used in `#areaRiservataPost`